# how to set the directory where Makefile exists so that I can run make from different directory using `make -C` option?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say in  `~/prj/abc/abcsim/abctsim/abcxyz/Makefile` there is a line below.

```
TOOLCHAIN_DIR   := $(PWD)/../../../prj1/tools/gcc_tools
```

If I'm in directory `~/test`, and if I run `make -C ~/prj/abc/abcsim/abctsim/abcxyz`, this doesn't work because the `$(PWD)` variable is set to `~/test`, not `~/prj/abc/abcsim/abctsim/abcxyz`. How can I get the directory path where the `Makefile` exists?
In bash there's something for this : [How can I get the source directory of a Bash script from within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-can-i-get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itsel)

Comment: Just to be entirely clear, make has no special handling at all for a variable `PWD`.  As far as make is concerned, `PWD` is just another variable that it inherits from the shell, like `PATH` and `USER` etc.  So, the value of `PWD` inside your makefile is whatever value your _shell_ passed in, which is the working directory of your shell before you invoked make.  As pointed out below, `CURDIR` is a _make_ variable that it will set to the working directory make is running in after `-C` is processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really use `make -C` (not `make -f`) and your Makefile is not included in another, you can simply use the [`CURDIR` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-CURDIR). GNU make sets it to the absolute path of the current directory when it starts, "*after it has processed any `-C` options*". So, in your case it should do exactly what you want.

Else, if you sometimes use `make -f` or if you have included Makefiles, you can put this as the first line of any of your Makefiles (or, at least, before any `include` statement):

```
HERE := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

and then use `$(HERE)` to refer to this Makefile's directory. See [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029) for the details.

Note: I was almost sure this question would be a duplicate. Surprisingly I searched SO for a clear answer and found only old answers that first suggest shell calls before using make built-ins or wrong answers (using `firstword` instead of `lastword`, for instance).